# How to create a combo box(drop down list) with button controls for window form tool strip???

Tags: forms, window

Like a **layer control** drop down in **AutoCAD**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself...

I create a user control which inherit the combo box class,this control works fine for me like a normal combo box.

Here is a code, that may help you to understand more about this control.

public partial class dropdown : ComboBox

```
{
    public dropdown()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure we're not trying to draw something that isn't there.
        if (e.Index >= this.Items.Count || e.Index <= -1)
            return;

        // Get the item object.
        object item = this.Items[e.Index];
        if (item == null)
            return;

        // Draw the background color depending on 
        // if the item is selected or not.
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            // The item is selected.
            // We want a blue background color.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Moccasin), e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            // The item is NOT selected.
            // We want a white background color.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
        }
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
        }
        // Draw the items...
        LayerEdit le = (LayerEdit)item;
        string text = le.LayerName.ToString();
        SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font);

        // Draw layer visible(on/off)...
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(byteArrayToImage(le.Visible), 2, 1 + e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2, 14, 14);
        // Draw layer Lock...
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(byteArrayToImage(le.Lock), 18, 1 + e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2, 15, 14);
        // Draw layer plot...
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(byteArrayToImage(le.Plot), 37, 1 + e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2, 14, 14);
        // Draw layer color... 
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml(le.ColourValue));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 55, 4 + e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2, 10, 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 55, 4 + e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2, 10, 10);
        // Draw layer name...
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(68, e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2));
    }
    //convert bytes into image...
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer?